# How to modify Chrome newtab.css from within a Chrome theme?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, themes, css

I want to modify the CSS for new tab page. NOT make new tab page. I already made a new tab page, but many users installing my themes won't also install the new tab page extension. So I want to modify the CSS on the new tab page for those who ONLY want my theme.

It is my understanding that `chrome://theme/css/newtab.css` is the stylesheet I need to change.
Feel free to tell other ways to add CSS to the ORIGINAL new tab page in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The default chrome theme is not designed to be editable by the end users. The resource files, including CSS, for Chrome's default theme used to be stored in theme.dll, and within chrome.dll itself for newer versions.

You can follow the [instructions here](http://chromespot.com/forum/chrome-themes-discussion/348-tutorial-editing-google-chrome-theme.html) if you are adventurous to hack DLL files.

The best source of guide for editing Chrome themes is still the official [Chrome Developer Themes documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes.html).

Answer (score 0):

> How to modify Chrome newtab.css from within a Chrome theme?

You can't, for two reasons:

1. Chrome *themes* are extremely restricted in scope -- the only thing they can do is provide colors and/or background images for the user interface (e.g, toolbar and tab bar) and new-tab page. They cannot make other changes to the appearance of the browser or override CSS for any web content (including the new-tab page).
2. Even if you meant a Chrome *extension*, extensions can only replace the new-tab page. They cannot alter or interact with the default new-tab page in any way.